# Is it possible to create a tree in F# where each Node also knows its parent?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, tree

The usual tree type looks something like

```
type Tree<'LeafData,'INodeData> =
   | LeafNode of 'LeafData
   | InternalNode of 'INodeData * Tree<'LeafData,'INodeData> seq
```

Is it possible to use a tree type that could be used in a purely functional way but still gives access to the parent of each node?

Comment: F# supports recursive value initialization with `let rec` but I find it a strange feature and I would use regular classes with active patterns instead

Comment: You could define a forest of vertices that know their parents like this: `type Vertex<'a> = { Parent : Vertex<'a> option; Data : 'a }`. That's probably not what you have in mind, but if you want two-way linked trees, that's going to be more unwieldy. It's not a normal thing to do in FP. There's probably a better solution, but it's hard to tell... What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkSeemann thank you for your suggestion. The question came up when trying to solve the day 7 puzzle of 2022 advent of code. It's about navigating and manipulating a virtual file system. The command "cd .." should change the current node to the parent and I was looking for an efficient way to do it while keeping the code immutable.

Comment: You can typically 'thread' a 'state' variable (here, an immutable stack of directories) through an algorithm. See e.g. my article [Recurse](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/01/recurse) for an introduction to the concept.

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks for the link. With that info I could come up with something that allows me to know the parent node of the current node but how would that help updating the parent node - let's say for 'cd ..' and adding a new file? I would still have to search for the parent node from the root of the tree but instead of trying to find a node which has the current node as child I could search for the node (the parent) directly. Not much of a difference?

Comment: This year I've been doing Advent of Code in Python, so I used a mutable stack representing the 'current' directory and a for loop, but as I wrote, the equivalent function is to pass an immutable stack around as an argument that you can manipulate. When you `cd` into a directory, put it on the stack. When you `cd ..`, pop the stack.

Comment: Using the stack method instead of building the tree seems like a great idea. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and no.

In a purely functional setting, its best to lookup "Tree Zipper" (there are all sorts of zippers).

These purely functional data structures allow you to navigate through a data structure (here a tree) without having to embed an explicit reference to 'parent' in the data structure itself.

The tree doesnt know its parent, but the zipper knows the 'path' to a specific node, and so it knows the parent.

for an F# overview see
https://tomasp.net/blog/tree-zipper-query.aspx/

(in response to your question ive included many more links and references, but the size of the response means I can't give you exactly what u want off the shelf)

There's a description of zippers in Haskell, but don't be too alarmed its quite accessible
http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers

There's paper somewhere about using differentiation to derive the data structure - though its slightly heavy going.
(theres a section of this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers towards the bottom that explains the mechanics)

there's this

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rosezipper-0.2/docs/Data-Tree-Zipper.html

but my haskell is too rusty to be able to translate this very easily

There is a binary tree zipper in
[FSharpx.Collections.Experimental](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-experimental-binarytreezipper.html)

Comment: That's a great article. Thank you for the link. Could you comment on how the zipper would look like for a non binary tree?

Comment: Ive added some more references...but the without scratching my head for an hour and remembering how to derive these things (its pretty mechanical), I can't find anything direct.
If you know ocaml/haskell u can probably dig out an example somewhere google "rosetree zipper"