# Create bi-directional tree in F#

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#

I am trying to define and create a tree structure where the parent knows the children and vice versa.

I created the following F# code which does not show any warnings (in fsx) and also seems to compile fine.

```
type Parent = {
    Name : string
    Age : int
    Children : Child list }
and Child = {
    Name : string
    Parent : Parent }    

let createParent name children = 
  { Name = name
    Age = 42
    Children = children }

let createChild name parent = 
  { Name = name
    Parent = parent }

let create name kids =
    let rec makeChild name = createChild name parent
    and makeParent name = createParent name children
    and parent = name |> makeParent 
    and children = kids |> List.map makeChild
    parent

create "Peter" [ "Sarah"; "Max" ]
|> printfn "%A"
```

But when I run this script I can see that "Children" is null.

Am I missing something or can such a data structure simply not be constructed in F#?

Comment: This looks a lot like an [F# compiler bug](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12384) that I reported a few years ago. Unfortunately, I don't think it's been fixed. Ending up with a null `Children` is a strong indicator that the compiler made a mistake.

Comment: I don't know about the particular language issue, but the overall implied question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74844575/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann thx i ll check out this question! meanwhile similar solution proposal was shared with me via X/Twitter (https://gist.github.com/Savelenko/d97a7897ee2f7c8a04fae37be4eb3848)